# How to remove or add an item to a jagged array in javascript using ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6

Say I have the following jagged array

```
var data = [
            ['a','b','c'],
            ['d','e',['f','g']],
            ['h','i','j']
          ];
```

and I want to be able to remove 'f' so that result is going to look like

```
var data1 = [
            ['a','b','c'],
            ['d','e',['g']],
            ['h','i','j']
          ];
```

Similarly I want to add 'f' after 'h' in the array above to give me

```
var data2 = [
            ['a','b','c'],
            ['d','e',['g']],
            ['h','f','i','j']
          ];
```

how can I achieve this in javascript or ES6? please note my jagged arrays can be multiple level deep the above just serves as an example.

so I need functions like
`data.remove('f')` to result in data1
`data1.addafter('h','f')` to result in data2

I tried a recursive function like below but unable to crack it...

```
function arrmap([head, ...tail], fn) {   
    return tail.length === 0 ? [fn(head)] : [fn(head), ...map(tail, fn)];  
}
```

Comment: do you have only one same value?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes that's correct, all the values in the jagged array or unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive combination of map and filter. In this case, I would just go with a recursive function with a `for...of` loop:

```js
const fn = arr => {
  const r = []
  
  for(const item of arr) {
    if(Array.isArray(item)) r.push(fn(item))    
    else if(item === 'h') r.push('h', 'f')
    else if(item !== 'f') r.push(item)  
  }
  
  return r;
}

const data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e',['f','g']],['h','i','j']]
          
const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

If you need a more generic approach, you can extract `fn`:

```js
const nestedMap = (arr, fn) => 
  arr.reduce((r, item) => {    
    const val = Array.isArray(item) ? [nestedMap(item, fn)] : fn(item)
    
    return val !== undefined ? r.concat(val) : r
  }, [])

const data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e',['f','g']],['h','i','j']]
          
const result = nestedMap(data, item => {
  if (item === 'h') return ['h', 'f']
  if (item !== 'f') return item
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Ori Drori exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: thanks for the update how can the function return a cloned array member of the item. e.g. when matched on 'h' I would want to clone and return the cloned array?

Comment: I've updated the 2nd solution to use reduce and concat, and create a new array when the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not adding much to Ori's original solution, but, you can also utilize closures with the same generic approach Ori mentioned:

```js
const nestedMap = (fn) => (arr) => {
  const r = []
  
  for(const item of arr) {
    if(Array.isArray(item)) r.push(nestedMap(fn)(item))
    else {
      const val = fn(item)

      if (val) r.push(...val)
    }
  }
  
  return r;
}

const data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e',['f','g']],['h','i','j']]


const addAfter = nestedMap((item) => {
    if (item === 'h') return ['h', 'f']
    if (item !== 'f') return [item]
});

const remove = nestedMap((item) => {
    if (item === 'f') return []
    return [item];
});

console.log(addAfter(data));
console.log(remove(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for data processing tasks like this. It's very powerful once you wrap your head around how to use it. Here is how you'd solve your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const rm = (v, input) => objectScan(['**[*]'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value === v) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

const ins = (after, v, input) => objectScan(['**[*]'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value === after) {
      parent.splice(property + 1, 0, v);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

const data = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', ['f', 'g']], ['h', 'i', 'j'] ];

console.log(rm('f', data));
// => true
console.log(rm('f', data)); // already removed
// => false
console.log(data);
// => [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e', [ 'g' ] ], [ 'h', 'i', 'j' ] ]

console.log(ins('x', 'f', data)); // can not find 'x'
// => false
console.log(ins('h', 'f', data));
// => true
console.log(data);
// => [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e', [ 'g' ] ], [ 'h', 'f', 'i', 'j' ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

As this was brought back up, and the current solutions seem more complex than necessary, here's an approach using `flatMap` for each:

```js
const removeVal = (val, xs) =>
  xs .flatMap ((x) => x == val ? [] : Array.isArray(x) ? [removeVal (val, x)] : [x]) 

const addAfter = (prev, val, xs) =>
  xs .flatMap ((x) => x == prev ? [x, val] : Array.isArray(x) ? [addAfter (prev, val, x)] : [x])

const data = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e',['f','g']], ['h','i','j']]

const data1 = removeVal ('f', data)
const data2 = addAfter ('h', 'f', data1)

console .log ('original', data)
console .log ('after removal', data1)
console .log ('after add', data2)
console .log ('original', data) // unchanged
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

As demonstrated, these do not change your input structure, but create parallel ones with the changes applied.

Note that these remove *every* `'f'` and adds one after *every* `'h'`.  This shouldn't be a problem given the stated requirements, but it could be an issue in some circumstances.

OriDrori talked about a combination of `map` and `filter`.  `flatMap` often makes that combination unnecessary.  It can be a pretty powerful tool.